# Could not find a subcommand named "ios" for "flutter build" error

Tags: flutter, dart, build, flutter-build, flutter-ios-build

I want to export my app to an ios device.However when I use `flutter build ios` this error happens.

> Could not find a subcommand named "ios" for "flutter build".

> Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and options.

and also that's what's inside the build -h :

```
Available subcommands:
  aar         Build a repository containing an AAR and a POM file.
  apk         Build an Android APK file from your app.
  appbundle   Build an Android App Bundle file from your app.
  bundle      Build the Flutter assets directory from your app.
  web         Build a web application bundle.
  windows     Build a Windows desktop application.
```

I'm kinda new in Flutter and stackoverflow,so I'd be glad if you can help me.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have an iOS directory? If so, you should have the command `flutter build ipa`

Comment: To build ios you need to be using a Mac

Comment: Thank you for your answers.Yes, looks like as you said, I need to have a Mac PC in order to get an IOS build.